# ¿cambiar tamaño de la hoja para que su contenido se ajuste al tamaño de la tabla pdf jsPDF-AutoTable v3.5.9?

Tags: jquery, datatables, jspdf

estoy usando jsPDF-AutoTable para exportar mis tablas a pdf, pero tengo problemas cuando las tablas tienen mucho contenido (columnas), no queda correctamnete el diseño de la tabla en el pdf final, como hago para hacer que el pdf se ajuste al tamaño de la tabla, y que me sirva para varias tablas sin necesidad de hacer lo mismo por cada una:

ejemplo este es el resultado que obtengo cuando genero el pdf, todas columnas se comprimen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi codigo js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table3=$(".datatable2").DataTable({dom: 'Bfrtip',
        dom: 'Blftipr',
        buttons:[
            {
                extend:    'copy',
                text:      '<i class="fa  fa-copy"></i> ',
                title: tittleoage,
                titleAttr: 'Exportar a Excel',
                className: 'btn btn-secondary'
            },
            {
                text:      '<i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i>',
                titleAttr: 'Exportar a Excel',
                className: 'btn btn-success',
                action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
                    $('#search_all').tableExport({
                        type:'excel'
                    });
                }
            },
            {
                //extend:    'pdfHtml5',
                text:      '<i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i> ',
                title: tittleoage1,
                filename: tittleoage,
                titleAttr: 'Exportar a PDF',
                className: 'btn btn-danger',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: ':not(.noexportar)'
                },
                action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {

                    var doc = new jsPDF();
                    doc.autoTable({ html: '#search_all', tableWidth: 'auto', tableLineWidth: number = 2, tableLineColor: Color = 200});
                    doc.save('table.pdf');
                    /* $('#search_user').tableExport({
                        fileName: tittleoage,
                        type:'pdf',
                        jspdf: {
                            orientation: 'l',
                                   format: 'a3',
                                   margins: {left:10, right:10, top:20, bottom:20},
                                   autotable: {styles: {fillColor: 'inherit',
                                   textColor: 'inherit'},
                                    tableWidth: 'auto'}
                        }
                    }); */
                }
            },
        colReorder: true,
        keys: true
    });
          
});
```

link del plugin: https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable/releases/tag/v3.5.9

Comment: tenia entendido que el plugin DataTable ya traía eso nativa-mente...

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez datatables ofrece la buttons para exportar a excel,pdf,etc pero datatables no esta soportado para tablas con colspan y rowspan, por lo que tuve la necesida de buscar otros plugins y este ofrece una excelente compatibilidad con lo que necesito, el probleme es de el tamaño de las tablas.

Comment: puedes revisar si esta solución en el foro en ingles te ayuda: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32679154/4717133 creo que esto te hace falta: `new jsPDF('l', 'pt', pdfsize);` me avisas si te funciona para agregarlo como solucion.

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez sí bro, funciono como lo esperaba en las tablas con muchas columnas. claro que para tablas pueqeñas ahora aumenta el tamaño de las columnas, habra forma de hacer que solo aplique el estilo de la hoja "ao" solo a tablas con muchas filas que se desborden de la hoja del tamaño por defecto?

Comment: Déjame reviso y te cuento...

Comment: puedes intentar con styles: { columnWidth: 'wrap' }; y me comentas o Tienes que aplicarle un ancho fijo a las columnas, si por alguna razon la columna mide mas se adaptara hasta un minimo no un maximo; seria conveniente que muestres el codigo html con el que se genera la tabla etc si es posible un ejemplo en tu post con sniped.

Comment: lo unico que necesito es que si la tabla es pequeña entonces el tamaño de la hoja tambien se adate (asi puedo reutilizar la función muchas veces sin preocuparme por el tamaño de la tabla), ya sea legal, carta, a0, a1,etc, styles: { columnWidth: 'wrap' }; con esta función no logro que pase eso, seguro porque anterioemente ya estoy definiendo el tamaño new jsPDF('l', 'pt', pdfsize); a0.

Comment: bueno la única forma de darte una solución seria los posible códigos html

Comment: te comento con esta funcion {tableWidth: 'wrap'} se reduce el tamaño de la tabla pero el de la hoja sigue igual.

Comment: te comento que lo mas optimo es que la hoja siempre sea del mismo tamaño y que juegues con el tamaño del contenido...ya que despues que quieras manipular el tamaño de la hoja te vas a topar el problema de las impresoras... Etc

Comment: por esperienia landscape y 8.5*14 es el estándar para tirar reportes en pdf

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112091/discussion-between-cris19n-and-francisco-nunez).